# Polymer: Drawer panel closes when swiping sideways while scrolling

Tags: polymer, swipe, polymer-1.0, drawer

Heyo. I'm using a `paper-drawer-panel` for my app. The panel contains quite a lot of stuff, so I'm having to scroll up and down to see everything.

Unfortunately, on my phone there's an issue. When scrolling up and down (with the usual variation to the left and right), I often accidentally close the drawer because it will close after swiping for only a few pixels to the side.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening, maybe I can disable drawer closing while scrolling up and down?

```
    <paper-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" responsive-width="1000px" drawer-width="275px" left-drawer>
        <div id="drawer" drawer>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>...
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
        <div main></div>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
```

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Number property edgeSwipeSensitivity to control this.  From the [Polymer docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel#property-disableEdgeSwipe):

**edgeSwipeSensitivity:** How many pixels on the side of the screen are sensitive to edge swipes and peek.

You can also disable with properties **disableEdgeSwipe** or **disableSwipe**.

Comment: that's for opening a drawer, not for "not closing it" if you know what I mean. Opening is fine as it is, it's just closing to soon

Comment: @Yorrd you can't add "disableSwipe" to it once it's open?

Comment: well then i can't close it at all via swipe. I just want to make it less sensitive when it's open